# Yii2 date format from 2 digit year to 4 digit

Tags: php, date, yii2, formatter

I have a date like this: `17-05-17` and I would like to show it like this: `2017-05-17`.

```
\Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('17-05-17')
\Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('17-05-17', 'php:Y-m-d');
```

Both are showing `0017-05-17`. Can you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lowercase `y` to parse date with 2-digit year:

```
$parsed = \DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m-d', '17-05-17');
$formatted = \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($parsed, 'php:Y-m-d');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: This is the right answer. Many thanks! I've also found this php function `DateTime::createFromFormat` but I was thinking, maybe it's in a Yii2 function also implemented.

Comment: Yii is using `createFromFormat()` or `IntlDateFormatter` internally for parsing dates.

Answer (score 1):

Use These :

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('17-05-17', 'php:Y-m-d');
```

Refer : https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-formatting

Comment: I have tried this one also, but it's giving also 0017-05-17 back.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `dateFormat` property for `Class yii\i18n\Formatter` in the components or by passing a parameter to the function

> `$dateFormat` public property The default format string to be used to
>   format a date. This can be "short", "medium", "long", or "full", which
>   represents a preset format of different lengths.
>
> It can also be a custom format as specified in the ICU manual.
>   Alternatively, this can be a string prefixed with php: representing a
>   format that can be recognized by the PHP date()-function.

in the config

```
'components'=>[
    'formatter'=>[
        'dateFormat'=>'yyyy/MM/dd' //ICU FORMAT
         //or php format
        //'dateFormat'=>'php:y/m/d' //php FORMAT 
    ]
]
```

and use it like

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($date);
```

or pass it in the parameter

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($date,'yyyy/MM/dd');
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. The output is the same.

Comment: @user2511599 you are not using correctly the format for date